# Creating tag QNames from element text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two questions connected with transformation XML to XML.

1. How make a new element which name is value of existing element (in my example the value of existing element `<author>` is Mike and I want to make a new tag named Mike).
2. How make a new element which attribute name is value of existing element (in my example the value of existing element `<grade>` is 5 and I want to make a new tag named Mike with attribute name "5"). Here is my example:

Existing XML:

```
<art>
  <images>
    <image>
      <title>Cat</title>
      <author>Mike</author>
      <grade>5<grade>
    </image>
    <image>
      <title>Snake</title>
      <author>John</author>
      <grade>4<grade>
    </image>
  </images>
</art>
```

New element inside tag art:

```
<authors>
  <Mike grade="5">
    <field_of_art>photography</field_of_art>
  </Mike>
</authors>
```

Comment: Note that I've slightly edited your question - you shouldn't normally include tag names in titles, and I've slightly clarified your question in the title.

Comment: @Sigger Are you sure you want do this? It's bad practice to put data in element names; it makes it very difficult for the recipient to process the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do this using `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` tags:

```
<!-- assumes the current context is an image tag -->
<xsl:element name="{author}">
    <xsl:attribute name="grade">
        <xsl:value-of select="grade" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <field_of_art>photography</field_of_art>
</xsl:element>
```

But be aware - if the `author` tag contains spaces or invalid characters it won't work.  For example, if you have an `<author>Mike 2</author>`, the stylesheet will fail because tag names can't have spaces, or if there were an `<author>Mike&amp;Jane</author>` it would fail as well.

Comment: And where in XSLT code i should put this fragment of code to create a new XML by MSXSL with new tags?

Comment: probably in an `xsl:template` that matches `//image`, with another template to produce the outer/root tag(s).

Comment: @Sigger Please edit your question and add the **complete** result you expect to get from transforming the given XML.